# How to access req.host in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am newbie to the node.js world. I am using passportjs library for authenticating the user with api key. What I am trying to do is that along with api key. I also want to check the host name of the request.

```
app.post('/api/authenticate', 
  passport.authenticate('localapikey'),//passport module method to authenticate the api key
  function(req, res) {
    console.log('Authenticated');
  });
```

I don't know how passportjs calling the below function. But it definitely calling the function after a post request is coming to the path '/api/authenticate'. I also want to access the req.host in the below function.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(apikey, done) {
    console.log(req.host);
}
```

Is it possible? Any insight into this would highly be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the passReqToCallback option. See the bottom of this page for details:

You must update your code like this:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  function(req, apikey, done) {
      console.log(req.host);
  }
));
```

http://passportjs.org/guide/authorize/